# conexion servidor remoto pyodbc

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-access

Estimados estoy trabajando en una base de datos en ms access

Realizo una consulta de forma local y funciona todo bien con el modulo pyodbc les dejo la sintax:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\Doron E\\Desktop\\Test\\testdb.accdb;")
```

no encuentro la manera como realizar la consulta a un servidor remoto.. alguien que sea mas entendido que me pudiese ayudar..

muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyodbc

server = 'xxxx'

database = 'xxx'

username = 'xx'

password = 'xxx'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

> El Driver es el conector (access, sql server,etc)